# Making select from JS array Jquery

Tags: jquery, loops, each

I have

```
var updateActive = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Koka Kola",
    "qty": "22",
    "price": "333",
    "active": "Yes"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Pizza",
    "qty": "1",
    "price": "1",
    "active": "Yes"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Jupi",
    "qty": "2",
    "price": "25000"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Jupi",
    "qty": "333",
    "price": "333"
}]
```

var message = "
                    ";

And array like that i can loop

```
$.each(updateActive, function (_, val) {
        val.id;
        val.name;
});
```

But i have problem how to put that values in loop in var message?
like

```
<option value="val.id">val.name</option>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create DOM option elements in a loop and attach them to your dynamically created select like this:

```js
var updateActive = [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Koka Kola",
    "qty": "22",
    "price": "333",
    "active": "Yes"
}, {
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Pizza",
    "qty": "1",
    "price": "1",
    "active": "Yes"
}, {
    "id": "3",
    "name": "Jupi",
    "qty": "2",
    "price": "25000"
}, {
    "id": "4",
    "name": "Jupi",
    "qty": "333",
    "price": "333"
}];
var message = "<select class='form-control' required name='article[]'></select>";
var select = $(message).get(0);
$.each(updateActive, function (_, val) {
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.id = val.id;
  option.innerHTML = val.name;
  select.appendChild(option);
});
alert(select.outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tefag/1/edit)**

```
var message = "<select class='form-control' required name='article[]'></select>";
var $msg = $(message); // Convert to jQuery element 
var options = "";      // Create a String To concatenate HTML Option Elements

$.each(updateActive, function (idx, val) {
  options += '<option value="'+val.id+'">'+val.name+'</option>'; // Concat
});

$msg.html( options );  // Finally set String as Element's HTML
```

Without string concatenation you can directly `.append()` to Element:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/tefag/2/edit)**

```
var message = "<select class='form-control' required name='article[]'></select>";
var $msg = $(message); // Convert to jQuery element

$.each(updateActive, function (idx, val) {  
  $msg.append('<option value="'+val.id+'">'+val.name+'</option>');
});
```